# Incorrect variable range behavior in RooFit

Tags: c++, root-framework

The RooFit package allows me to import some TTree branches, but it constrains values included in those branches between the min and max value set by a RooRealVar. For instance:

```cpp
RooRealVar t1("t1", "Some variable", 0.0, 1.0);
RooDataSet data("data", "My Dataset", RooArgSet(t1), Import(*myttree));
```

so long as the TTree `myttree` contains a branch called `t1`. This is all fine and good, until you start getting close to floating point values in the range. My particular problem occurs because I have a variable like `t1` which maps to some variable with an exponential distribution. I'm trying to fit this distribution, but the fits fail for values of `t1 ~ 0.0`. My solution was to just change the range a bit to cut off potential events where the stored value of `t1` in the tree is actually zero or close to it (all the following code is run in the ROOT interpreter, but I have confirmed it works in compiled code as well):

```cpp
root[0] RooRealVar t1("t1", "Some variable", 0.001, 1.0);
```

However, note the following annoying behavior:

```cpp
root[1] t1 = 0.000998;
root[2] t1.getVal();
(double) 0.0010000000
// this is correct, as 0.000998 < 0.001 so RooFit set it as the lower limit
root[3] t1 = 0.000999;
root[4] t1.getVal();
(double) 0.00099900000
// this is incorrect.
```

Yes, the extra zero is printed in the second case, which I also don't understand, but I'm mostly concerned with the failure to recognize that `0.000999 < 0.001`. When I compare these values later in an if-statement, I find that C++ can tell the difference. Everything appears to be double precision [here](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classRooRealVar.html#a14df6c26a256d20adcb4be71f6abb4de), and I've been tracing through the code to see where the precision error seems to crop up. Correct me if I'm wrong, but a float should still hold these numbers up to comparison precision, right? What's going on here? If this is some floating point error problem, what's the best way to resolve it? I have several events with values like `t1 = 0.000999874`, and changing the bounds to something like `0.0001` doesn't really help either, there are still events which live on this edge.

Edit: I want to emphasize that while this is probably a floating point problem, it really shouldn't be. For instance, the following code works:

```cpp
root[0] RooRealVar t1("t1", "Some variable", 0.001, 1.0);
root[1] t1 = 0.000999;
root[2] t1.getVal() < 0.001;
(bool) true
```

Answer (score 1):

Well everyone, I found the answer (and I hate it). It actually has very little to do with floating point arithmetic, and I'm honestly not sure why the code was written this way. From the [source code](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/RooAbsRealLValue_8cxx_source.html#l00093) that determines if a value is "in range":

```cpp
bool RooAbsRealLValue::inRange(double value, const char* rangeName, double* clippedValPtr) const
{
  // double range = getMax() - getMin() ; // ok for +/-INIFINITY
  double clippedValue(value);
  bool isInRange(true) ;
 
  const RooAbsBinning& binning = getBinning(rangeName) ;
  double min = binning.lowBound() ;
  double max = binning.highBound() ;
 
  // test this value against our upper fit limit
  if(!RooNumber::isInfinite(max) && value > (max+1e-6)) {
    clippedValue = max;
    isInRange = false ;
  }
  // test this value against our lower fit limit
  if(!RooNumber::isInfinite(min) && value < min-1e-6) {
    clippedValue = min ;
    isInRange = false ;
  }
 
  if (clippedValPtr) *clippedValPtr=clippedValue ;
 
  return isInRange ;
}
```

As we can see here, RooFit *doesn't* actually check if `min < val < max` or even `min <= val <= max` but rather `min - 1e-6 < value < max + 1e-6`! I couldn't find a single place where this was documented explicitly, but I'm even more concerned that there is a [separate implementation](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/RooAbsRealLValue_8cxx_source.html#l00493) of `inRange` which takes a variable name (or comma separated list of variable names) and returns a result which is incompatible with the prior implementation:

```cpp
bool RooAbsRealLValue::inRange(const char* name) const
{
  const double val = getVal() ;
  const double epsilon = 1e-8 * fabs(val) ;
  if (!name || name[0] == '\0') {
    const auto minMax = getRange(nullptr);
    return minMax.first - epsilon <= val && val <= minMax.second + epsilon;
  }
 
  const auto& ranges = ROOT::Split(name, ",");
  return std::any_of(ranges.begin(), ranges.end(), [val,epsilon,this](const std::string& range){
    const auto minMax = this->getRange(range.c_str());
    return minMax.first - epsilon <= val && val <= minMax.second + epsilon;
  });
}
```

Here, we can see the creation of an `epsilon = 1e-8 * fabs(val)` rather than the arbitrary `1e-6` given in the first definition. This comparison uses a `<=` rather than a `<` also. It should be noted that the method used to filter trees when imported in this way uses the first implementation ([source here](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/RooAbsRealLValue_8cxx_source.html#l00141)).

Somewhere along the way (I'm not entirely sure where actually), some of these arbitrary comparisons lead to the following paradoxical behavior:

```cpp
root[0] RooRealVar t1("t1", "Some variable", 0.001, 1.0);
root[1] t1 = 0.001 - 1e-6;
(RooAbsArg &) RooRealVar::t1 = 0.000999  L(0.001 - 1) 
root[2] t1 = 0.001 - 1e-8 * 0.001;
(RooAbsArg &) RooRealVar::t1 = 0.001  L(0.001 - 1)
root[3] t1 = 0.00099999999;
(RooAbsArg &) RooRealVar::t1 = 0.001  L(0.001 - 1)
```

I would classify this as a bug. Under no circumstances should `0.00099900000` be classified as within the range of `(0.001 - 1)` where `0.00099999999` is not!